# How do I create a another login system under sub url?

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose **www.domain.com** is my whereas the system admin can access the site except the individual department . **www.domain.com/computer-science** is an url of computer department whereas the computer science department staff only access, other has no right even the system admin. And computer science department staff has no write to access the other portion of site except **www.domain.com/computer-science** They has different database. How do I create a another login system login system for **www.domain.com/computer-science** ?

The folder and sub folder like below pic :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want an all-or-nothing authentication for each path, you can restrict the session cookie using [session-set-cookie-params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).  If you need anything more complicated, you probably need to create an authorization system with some kind of scope limiting functionality.